# Change language format of input fields

Tags: html, localization

I have following code

```
<html>
    <input type="date">
    <input type="number">
</html>
```

When my browser (Edge chromium or Chrome) is displayed in English I can see input values in English format.

[image]

When my browser is displayed in different language I can see input values in different format.

[image]

Is it possible to manage the displayed format from the application side? For example specify that numbers or dates in inputs has to be in specific language?

If no, the only workaround I can see is to use

- input type text
- and custom JavaScript date picker

I tried to use
`html lang tag`, but it does not seem to have an effect on input fields

Any idea?